# How can I do word processing with minimal copy and allocation?

Tags: c#, memory, data-structures

I have a `Span<byte>` holding a buffer of characters. The buffer contains text. I want to count the frequency for each word. How can I do this with minimal allocation and copy and without using strings?
With strings is very simple I would put the words in a `Dictionary<string, int>` and would allow me to see if the current word is already in collection.

Trying to use as structure such as

```
ref struct Word
{
   public Span<byte> content;
   public int GetHashCode() {...}
   public bool Equals(Word other) {...}
}
```

won't work with dictionaries because dictionaries are allocated on heap while ref structs are not. I would like to use a collection to hold words which has less than O(n) Search time.

I do not require to use Span to hold words. The requirements are: minimal allocation and copy and fast search.

Comment: If you implement GetHashCode and Equals properly you can have a Dictionary<Word,int>, right?

Comment: I can't, ref structs can't be used in dictionaries since dictionaries are allocated on heap while ref structs are allocated on stack.